# How can a PyQt program be run on Ubuntu for phones?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, python, pyqt

I have a small PyQt program that I want to install on an Ubuntu phone. It is a simple toggle button GUI to set the phone into staged or windowed modes. How can this be done?

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QWidget,
    QToolTip, 
    QPushButton,
    QApplication,
    QVBoxLayout
)
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
import subprocess
import sys

def main():

    application = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(application.exec_())

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.button = QPushButton("toggle windowed/staged", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.button_action)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.button)
        self.show()

    def button_action(self):
        toggle_status = engage_command(
            command = "gsettings get com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode"
        ).strip("'")
        if toggle_status == "staged":
            engage_command("gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Windowed")
        elif toggle_status == "windowed":
            engage_command("gsettings set com.canonical.Unity8 usage-mode Staged")

def engage_command(
    command = None
    ):
    process = subprocess.Popen(
        [command],
        shell      = True,
        executable = "/bin/bash")
    process.wait()
    output, errors = process.communicate()
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Ubuntu touch uses Qt5 not Qt4 so using your program as is may make you have to include all of Qt4. There are also pyQt5 pacakges so this should not be that big of a deal I do not think.

Comment: @ianorlin Thanks for the suggestion. I have change the program to PyQt5. Would you have any idea on how to proceed?